# How to make my user login image different than my Apple ID image on my macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-id, user-account, monterey, login

I have a Macbook that is connected to my Apple ID. There is only one user on my computer so it's an admin account.

When I want to change the user login image, it automatically changes my Apple ID image to the same image.

How do I change my login user image without changing my Apple ID at the same time?

Comment: any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this behavior by disabling Contacts sync in the iCloud settings for the Apple ID on the computer. This is not ideal, since then your Contacts will no longer sync, but it does stop this behavior.